# React - onbeforeunload event never triggered

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I need to run code to clear data from local strorage when my react app is closed. I have tried what I saw in similar questions, but my onbeforeunload code does not seem to ever get run (I am on chrome if that matters).

App.tsx code:

```
    handleWindowClose() // never gets run
    {
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem('tabs')
        if (value !== null) {
            var loc = +value // convert to num
            window.localStorage.setItem('tabs', (loc - 1).toString());
        }
    }

componentWillMount()
{   
        var handle = this.handleWindowClose
        window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', (ev: any) => {
            // breakpoints in here do not trigger, alert does not show up
            // adding a long loop to delay does not actually delay the close operation
            ev.preventDefault();
            alert('you are closing')
            handle()
        });
}
```

Does anyone know why my onbeforeunload event is never triggered?

**Update** I have tried using the onbeforeunload, onpagehide, and onunload events. None of them seem to run in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "on" from "onbeforeunload" and it should work. Just in case, I created [a quick playground to demonstrate how it should be implemented](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-onbeforeunload-event-never-triggered-answer-di38w?file=/src/App.js:1621-1878).

Basically, I set up an effect hook to read localstorage every second, another effect hook which does delayed write to localstorage after 2.5 seconds, and another effect that implements 'beforeunload'. If you comment it out, you'll see the message be displayed without loading (since it wasn't removed).

The implementation of 'beforeunload':

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const onBeforeUnload = (ev) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("message");
  };
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);
}, []);
```